# How to create thumbnail of video from video url from server?

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I am using this function:

```
public Bitmap createVideoThumbNail(String path)
{
   return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
}
```

But it returns null when i pass server path of url

Comment: What is example of server path to test?

Answer (score 0):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is pretty useful in this scenario.

```
Glide.with(context).load(videoUrl).into(imageView)
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: It doesn't creates thumbnail but a blank space is created

Answer (score 0):

Download the video. Then create a thumbnail from the downloaded video. If the video is not on the device, Android cannot create a thumbnail for it.